# Is there an SEO impact of appending querystrings to cached assets/images (e.g. Image.jpg?1234)?

Tags: seo, query-string, cdn

We're having an issue where we need to append querystrings to assets to allow our CDN provider to see a new version of the same image.  The CDN provider (well nearly all CDN providers) can treat querystrings appended to an asset as a new version of the image.

Is there an SEO impact to appending a querystring to an image link to indicate it's a new version to the CDN?

Example: Search engines used to see that Image.jpg was referenced by many pages, now they would see that Image.jpg?1234 is referenced.  Will this have a negative impact on SEO?  Some of our image names have been linked to for quite some time and we wouldn't want to negatively impact our image rankings (in Google).

Comment: SEO for images. That's new for me. Do you want your images to appear high in google image search, or are you concert about the impact it has on you webpage ranking?

Answer (score 0):

Appending query strings could cause a canonicalization issue with your images. You might want to try adding the `Link: <URL>; rel="canonical"` http header to your image responses to canonicalize them back to the originating source. This way it'll be clear to the search engines that these are not new images.

One caveat ... This is a new implementation provided by Google => "[Supporting rel="canonical" HTTP Headers](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/06/supporting-relcanonical-http-headers.html)". So it's not clear whether this works for Bing / Yahoo at this time ... my guess is not yet.